# Upgrading Mobile Solution

Tags: android, mobile, java-me

Actually we have developed one mobile solution, which is used by our customers. But many customers are willing to download the application in the android mobile. But our solution does not get download in android mobile since we have only jad and jar files. So with this scenario whether I have to develop the same solution for android mobile or convert the exist jar or jad files to android support file extension like ( apk ). Which one will be better idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Direct installation of Jar/Jad not supported in android mobiles. Use some [third party convertor](http://www.netmite.com/android/) for convert .apk to .jar or .jar to .apk. But I'm **not sure** how its work or how its support on android mobiles. Also refer this [existing discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64745/moving-to-android-from-j2me). It will helps you.

Better you can go with Android development separately or use [cross platform mobile development](http://www.google.co.in/#hl=en&sugexp=ppwl&cp=34&gs_id=3p&xhr=t&q=cross+platform+mobile+development+tools&pf=p&sclient=psy-ab&source=hp&pbx=1&oq=cross+platform+mobile+development+&aq=0&aqi=g4&aql=&gs_sm=&gs_upl=&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.,cf.osb&fp=294a4d65b4385f70&biw=1280&bih=678).
Also you can use some third party framework like LWUIT. If you LWUIT, it will [supports both platform](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7401567/how-to-convert-j2me-running-lwuit-to-android). but you have to change something for both the development.

Answer (score 0):

Although Third party apps available to run jad/jar , but its not a good choice because app will face perfomance and support issue  .

so developer separate app for android.

Answer (score 0):

We have faced this situation earlier, We can port application to android, or can use third party. But I'll suggest you to develop entirely new application for Android if your solution does not require number of months to implement.