# Save a number using rms in j2me lwuit

Tags: java-me, lwuit, persistent, rms

What I have tried is to build a `Form` and inside that a `TextField` where the user can insert any number and click on "save" `Command` and the number should save in the rms, and now, even after the several times of opening the application and closing it, the saved value be there in the application. I honestly ask for help.

Answer (score 2):

Ok, you can use rms for that, but it would be more hard than build a xml file and write the data inside of it. This will help you 

 [XML parsing not working on android build of lwuit app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9175745/xml-parsing-not-working-on-android-build-of-lwuit-app/9181807#9181807)

Comment: does it work for normal nokia phones? i m developing app for nokia, not android, will it work?

Comment: i'm not able to import the `com.sun.lwuit.xml` i dont know what is the exact problem.

Comment: i'm sticking with rms since i am not that familiar with xml, i